# Zend hostname router: dynamic part is not specified

Tags: php, zend-framework, subdomain, router, hostname

I have setup a route like below in bootstrap.php:

```
$hostnameRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(
    ':param1.localhost',
    array(
    'controller' => 'index'
    )
);

$plainPathRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static('');

$router->addRoute('user', $hostnameRoute->chain($plainPathRoute));
```

But when I try to go to "test.localhost", it give the error message: "An application error happened: param1 is not specified".

How to resolve this?

Windows hosts and apache vhosts are configured, then the error is with Zend.

Comment: See my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204543/hostname-and-custom-routing-in-zend-framework-dont-work-together-for-me/11133748#11133748 because I think it solves your problem as well.